# Clustering lines based on start- and end point without knowing the number of clusters

Tags: python, line, hough-transform

I use Hough transformation to detect lines in a soccer field. Below is an example of the detected lines (**61 lines** in total):

[image]

All lines are the output of the `cv2.HoughLinesP`-function and are presented as a `numpy-array` in the following format:

```
 [x1, y1, x2, y2]
```

There are 3 distinct line groupes that I want to classify; `goal_line`, `goal_area_line` and `penalty_area_line`. The 4th line visible on the image is a line caused by the billboards and I want to ignore this one. 
I am struggling with choosing the number of clusters, *k*. This is because when the ball moves from the middle line towards the goal area, we first only see 1 line, namely `penalty_area_line`. When the ball moves further to the left, the camera will likely follow and we will see more lines. I use the following to calculate the gradient and intercept of each line:

```
def gradient_intercept(x1, y1, x2, y2):
   dx = x2 - x1
   dy = y2 - y1
   radius = math.atan2(-dy, dx)
   radius %= 2 * math.pi
   gradient = -math.degrees(radius)
   if gradient <= -180:
     gradient = gradient + 180
   gradient = gradient + 90
   intercept = y1 - gradient * x1

   return gradient, intercept
```

Next, I create a 2d-array for all the lines and use this to calculate a distance matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial as ss     

def distance_matrix(lines):
   xy = np.empty((0, 2), int)

   try:
      for line in lines:
         for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            gradient, intercept = gradient_intercept(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            xy = np.append(xy, [[0, gradient]], axis=0)
   except Exception as e:
      print(str(e))

   if len(xy) > 2:
      distance_matrix = ss.distance_matrix(xy, xy)
```

The function yields the following output:

```
[[0.        6.10702413 5.12577724 ... 1.11858265 0.02889456 2.02399679]
[6.10702413 0.         0.98124689 ... 7.22560678 6.07812957 4.08302733]
[5.12577724 0.98124689 0.         ... 6.24435989 5.09688267 3.10178044]
...
[1.11858265 7.22560678 6.24435989 ... 0.         1.14747721 3.14257944]
[0.02889456 6.07812957 5.09688267 ... 1.14747721 0.         1.99510223]
[2.02399679 4.08302733 3.10178044 ... 3.14257944 1.99510223 0.        ]]
```

Next, I need to cluster the lines together based on their intercept.
I assume that (in the case of 4 visible clusters)

```
  intercept_billboards > intercept_goal_line > intercept_goal_area_line > intercept_penalty_area_line
```

Searching through SO I believe that [`DBSCAN`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) is suitable for my case

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.2,min_samples=2)  # minimum of two lines in order to be considered a cluster
db.fit_predict(distance_matrix)
labels = db.labels_
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
```

Inspecting `n_clusters_` I see sometime values of 5 or 6. **Question**: What is exactly `eps`? Which scale is it? What could be an appropriate value in my case?
**Second question** Is my methodology (intercepts -> distance_matrix) a correct one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `intercept = y1 - gradient * x1` seems fishy. You want `intercept = y1 - (dy / dx) * x1` most likely.

Comment: Don't bother using clustering as such. Just check if two slope-intercept pairs are within some tolerance of each other. If they are, they're segments of the same line.

Comment: That being said, I'm working on a paper for a 1D clustering algorithm that should work in your case. I'll keep you in mind when I make it available.